# Express : Call to next in error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I am implementing a node + express js app, and I am having issues calling to the `next` function into the error handler.

I have a `render` middleware which is called by `next` in each each controler, and I would like it to be the same with my error handler. What I do in controler is putting some viewProperties in the `req`and then call the next middleware which retrieve these properties and render the response consequently.

```
function render(req, res, next) {

  // viewName, title, args
  var properties = req.viewProperties || {};

  // We only handle a res.send(message)
  if (properties.body) {

    res.send(properties.body);
    return;
  }

  // We only handle a res.redirect(url)
  if (properties.redirect) {

    res.redirect(properties.redirect);
    return;
  }

  properties.lang = req.app.get('lang');
  properties.title = properties.title || 'Message_Me';
  properties.connected = req.session ? req.session.connected : false;
  properties.firstname = req.session.userFirstname || 'anonymous';

  res.render(properties.name, properties);
}
```

When I try using this middleware with my error handler, using `next()` the request is just pending on client side, and never recieved.
So I try to create the same middleware as an error handler : The same function but with an arity of 4 and then call `next(err)` in my error handler. This time the response is revieved client side but it is not rendered properly, it only shows up the stack trace.

The only way I found, it to copy this function in my error handler and paste it instead of calling to `next`. I don't understand why it can't work properly ?

my error handler :

```
function redirectError(err, req, res, next) {

    // Ajax call running
    if (req.xhr) {

        req.viewProperties = { body : err.message };
        return next(err);
    }

    req.viewProperties = { name : 'layout/error', title : 'Erreur', message : err.message, err : err };

    // Here is the probleme
    next()
    // next(err);
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried another thing : I copied the `render` method into my error module as a simple function (not declared middleware). And then call to it instead of `next` in the `redirectError` error handler. that did the same behaviour. the function is called BUT nothing is recied on client side.

WHEREAS

If I copy the content of the `render` function INTO the `redirectError` everything works fine.

There really is something I don't understand here. It may be a deeper problem I have not yet noticed...
**Riddles In The Dark**

**EDIT N2**

I figured out my mistake !! I forgot a `return` statement in a `if` of another middleware. That made the `next`being called twice, and a very bad bahaviour...

As a conclusion, a good practice to adopt, is to always use `return` when calling next !

*And thank's to laggingreflex which made me carry on.*

Comment: Is `redirectError` the last middleware? If so there's nothing to goto `next` to, so not sure why you're calling that.

Comment: the last middleware is `render`. It is set after `redirectError` so there is indeed a next to go to. I even tested it with logs and the `render` middleware print it correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's an Error present (either thrown or passed through `next`) then only the next middleware which can handle the error (the one defined with arity of `(err,req,res,next)`) is called.

Conversely, if there *isn't* an Error present then the error handler middleware `(err,req,res,next)` is *not* called.

So in your case, your `redirectError` will *only* be called if there *is* an Error present, and your `render` only when there isn't.

To demonstrate:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    throw(new Error('testing...'));
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // This won't be called
});
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // But This would
    next(); // not passing any Error this time
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // So now this won’t be called
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // But this would
});
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but I know that. Actually, as I said in a previous comment, I put logs in the `render` method and they are all printed to the last line after passing through the error handler. that mean that the `res.render(...)` is called but the request is just pending on client side and I never get any response back. I can't understand why...

Comment: I see, I would've rather made this a comment but it was to long. Anyways. You can `render` logs (printed on client-side?) then how is the request still pending?

Comment: I forgot to say it is only server side logs. Iput some `consol.log()`in the render method and they were well printed on my server console after passing in the `redirectError`. that means that the call to `next()` worked well, and the `res.render(properties.name, properties);` is actually called. But I never recieve a thing on client side... Is there any format requirement for response that I would not apply, or anything ? For me it is a really weird behaviour.

Comment: I see. What's `properties.name, properties`? Also try putting another error handler middleware after render to see if any errors are thrown.

Comment: I just added an observation I add as an edit of my qeustion. If you may have a look. `properties` is an object containing model info for the view (I use jade). It's taken from the `req`. I put it in the `req` throughout the flow of middlewares.

Comment: What about adding another middleware that handles errors? `redirectError` is probably throwing an error which is why `render` isn't called since it can't handle errors (`err,req,res,next` arity)