# Express js middleware not working when error is passed alongside ,req,res and next

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, middleware

So , I am trying to implement CSRUF in express and I want to have custom errors thrown instead of the default error handling of the middleware [CSRUF example here](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#custom-error-handling).
The CSRF implemntetion is working correctly and when the token is invalid,an error is thrown in console and a response with a 403 status is send to browser.
I do not want the error to be handled by default.
When I create a custom error handler middleware as below,

```
 function (err,req, res, next) {
    console.log("reached")
    if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err)

    console.log("Not working")
    // handle CSRF token errors here
    res.status(500)
    res.send('form tampered with')
}
```

It appears that the middlware is not being implemented as the default error for CSRUF is being thrown.

Intrestingly,I noticed that when i have a custom middeware with an err parameter,the middleware appears to be ignored by the app.
Example(This works)

```
 function (req, res, next) {
     console.log("This is some middleware") //Console outputs
      next()
   
}
```

However,When I add a err or error parameter to the function as below,it appears as though the middleware is not being used

```
function (req, res, next) {
         console.log("This is some middleware.Err parameter has been passed") //Nothing is output to console
         next()
    }
```

I have read the [Express error handling documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) and done as required but i still face the error,What could be the issue and how do i handle such.

Comment: Do you call  `.use(errorhandler)` for each error handler after you call `.use()` for everything else? Error handlers must be `use`d last.

Comment: where specifically? Could you give me an illustration i get to understand it

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27889143/13675289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
When I place the error handler middleware just after the CSRUF everything works  i.e

```
app.post(route,middleware1,errorhandler,(req,res)={
//Any errors from middleware1 will now be catched by the errorhandler instead of the default error handler
//Some code here
})
```

The location of the errorhandler appears to play a big role